# How to return different types in the same function in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I cannot understand why, although I have declared the data types, the function does not accept the different return. I also tried to create a "Result" type but it was not enough to solve the problem.

Take a look at my code:

```
type Set a = [a]
type Bag a = [(a, Int)]
type Seq a = [a]

data ComposedType a = Set a | Bag [a] | Seq a deriving(Eq, Show)
data ComposedResult a = Res1 [a] | Res2 [(a, Int)]

-- This function get a list [a] and returns a list of tuples [(a, Int)]
occrs :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [(a, Int)]
occrs [] = []
occrs xs = toList (fromListWith (+) [(x, 1) | x <- xs])

--getElements :: ComposedType a -> ComposedResult a
getElements (Set a) = (Set (nub a))
getElements (Seq a) = (Seq (sort a))
getElements (Bag a) = (Bag (occrs a))
```

The error:

> - Couldn't match type ([a], Int) with '[a]'
>   Expected type: ComposedType [a]
>   Actual type: ComposedType ([a], Int)

> - In the expression: (Bag (occrs a))
>   In an equation for 'getElements':
>   getElements (Bag a) = (Bag (occrs a))

Comment: Note that `set` uses `a`, so that means that the *first* line needs a `ComposeType [a]`, not a `ComposeType a`., the same with `seq`. But now the `Bag` needs `b ~ (a, Int)`, hence the error.

Comment: You use `Set` both as a type alias and as a constructor name. These two uses are unrelated: the type definition `data ComposedType a = Set a | Bag [a] | Seq a` does not use the type `Set a` at all. Ditto for `Bag` and `Seq`. This is probably not what you wanted.

Comment: Do you believe the `Set` in `type Set a = [a]` and the `Set` in `data ComposedType a = Set a | ...` are related to each other? If so, that may be the core part of your confusion -- they are the same name, but in two distinct namespaces (the type namespace for the former and the computation namespace for the latter) -- and it might be worth adding an answer that discusses this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this does not work is because `Set (num a)` for example has type `ComposedType [a]`, whereas for the `Bag (occrs)`, it will require `ComposedTYpe (a, Int)`, since the `Bag` uses, in contrast to the other data constructors a list of `a`s: `[a]`.

If you make use of a `ComposedResult`, then you will need to use the `Res1` and `Res2` data constructors:

```
getElements :: (Eq a, Ord a) => ComposedType [a] -> ComposedResult a
getElements (Set b) = Res1 (nub b)
getElements (Seq b) = Res1 (sort b)
getElements (Bag b) = Res2 (occrs b)
```

but this will *still* not work. Indeed `Bag a` has a parameter `b`, but that `b` has as type `[[a]]`, and although `occrs` can work with a list of lists (since these are also an instance of `Ord` if the element is an instance of `ord`, this would mean that `occrs b` has type `[([a], Int)]` whereas the others (`nub b` and `sort b`), have type `[a]`, so that would again raise trouble.

We can fix this by concatenating for example the elements of `b` together:

```
getElements :: (Eq a, Ord a) => ComposedType [a] -> ComposedResult a
getElements (Set b) = Res1 (nub b)
getElements (Seq b) = Res1 (sort b)
getElements (Bag bs) = Res2 (occrs (concat bs))
```

but likely you made a mistake by specifying `[a]` as parameter for bag, you thus can fix the type and use:

```
data ComposedType a = Set a | Bag a | Seq a deriving (Eq, Show)

getElements :: (Eq a, Ord a) => ComposedType [a] -> ComposedResult a
getElements (Set b) = Res1 (nub b)
getElements (Seq b) = Res1 (sort b)
getElements (Bag b) = Res2 (occrs b)
```

Comment: I think you are missing a big issue: `ComposedType` does not make use of the `Set`, `Bag`, or `Seq` type aliases at all: it just holds a single `a` decorated with one of 3 constructors whose names happen to overlap with those types. Henrique N. Mendes probably intended instead that it actually hold a Set, Bag, or Seq.